# Why does MariaDB on Docker runs much slower than 'native' MariaDB package on the same Synology machine?

Tags: docker, mariadb, synology

There is a Synology DS1621xs+ (equiped with NVMe SSD cache and 24 GB RAM).
OS: Synology DSM 7.1
File System: btrfs
Docker version: 20.10.3

There is a MariaDB10 server running on Docker on this machine.

An identical database is running on the 'native' Synology MariaDB10 package on the same machine. (Dumped and copied from the Docker instance.)

Queries on the database of the 'native' MariaDB10 package run **much** faster than on the docker instance. Difference is at least 2.5x, but on some queries it is 20x.

What might be the reason of this huge perfomance difference, why are the queries slower on Docker than on the Synology Package version of MariaDB?

Dockerinfo:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 10
  Running: 7
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 36
 Server Version: 20.10.3
 Storage Driver: btrfs
  Build Version: Btrfs v4.0
  Library Version: 101
 Logging Driver: db
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs db fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 3fa00912415f3e9c6f82dd72119179d599efd13b
 runc version: 31cc25f16f5eba4d0f53e35374532873744f4b31
 init version: ed96d00 (expected: de40ad0)
 Security Options:
  apparmor
 Kernel Version: 4.4.180+
 Operating System:  (containerized)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 23.25GiB
 Name: NAS
 ID: ZLGI:KUWA:HOGC:3J6W:B6NJ:CZLJ:ZQP2:HAG5:3DP6:OEPX:5WRW:IHAJ
 Docker Root Dir: /volume2/@docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No kernel memory TCP limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
WARNING: No blkio weight support
WARNING: No blkio weight_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support
`
```

MariaDB container log:

```
2022-11-19T08:55:19.209130033Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 221119  9:55:19
2022-11-19T08:55:19.174115217Z  stdout  Version: '10.6.5-MariaDB-1:10.6.5+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2022-11-19T08:55:19.174011946Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
2022-11-19T08:55:19.167072919Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@mariadb-copy' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-19T08:55:19.163349561Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-11-19T08:55:19.163211778Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2022-11-19T08:55:19.161820288Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
2022-11-19T08:55:19.149901116Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-11-19T08:55:19.149840357Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-11-19T08:55:19.149391807Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.5 started; log sequence number 3282096825; transaction id 7204
2022-11-19T08:55:19.148296829Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-11-19T08:55:19.148223400Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-11-19T08:55:19.148147151Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-11-19T08:55:19.147243337Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-11-19T08:55:19.086673922Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-11-19T08:55:19.085986215Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2022-11-19T08:55:19.085469623Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-11-19T08:55:19.068551244Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2022-11-19T08:55:19.068528556Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-11-19T08:55:19.068487467Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using transactional memory
2022-11-19T08:55:19.068374374Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-11-19T08:55:19.049836283Z  stdout  2022-11-19  9:55:19 0 [Note] mysqld (server 10.6.5-MariaDB-1:10.6.5+maria~focal) starting as process 1 ...
2022-11-19T08:55:18.900158637Z  stdout  2022-11-19 09:55:18+01:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.3.14+maria~bionic started.
2022-11-19T08:55:18.892594609Z  stdout  2022-11-19 09:55:18+01:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-11-19T08:55:18.738312960Z  stdout  2022-11-19 09:55:18+01:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.3.14+maria~bionic started.
```

Comment: Please share Dockerfile and commands that you issued, also logs, docker, docker compose version, os version. Use the edit button on your question to update   it.

Comment: What filesystem does your Synology host use? If it's not the same as your docker container, you could be seeing performance loss from the file system translation.

Comment: @zsolt: thank you, I've shared the log of the container and the docker info, also added OS information. I did not use docker compose, I just pulled the official mariadb container by Synology Docker application's GUI, and created the container from that. I'm not sure what commands would you like to see. The SQL queries?

Comment: @sobek: Synology host use btrfs file system. How can I check what file system does the container use? Isn't it always the same as host's file system?

Comment: How do you have 10.6.5 and 10.3.14 versions in your container log? Which version are you actually measuring on native and container? Please look at using the 10.6.11 version, there's a [few significant fixes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-10-6-11-release-notes/). Are you comparing this to Synology's [MARIADB10{.3.32}](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/packages/MariaDB10). Is a version like comparion possible?

Comment: I have no idea what does 10.3.14 do in the log file. :-D
Container is 10.6.5 (and I'll update it to the latest immediately), "native" (packaged) is 10.3.32. (Synology updates their packages quite unfrequently.) So, actually still the newer is the slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MariaDB changed [innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_flush_method) in 10.6 to aid the high end performance. As such MariaDB-10.6 is much more reliant on a `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `innodb_log_file_size` to gain read/write performance.

As a work around, test 10.6 with `innodb_flush_method=fsync`. btrfs is significantly newer than today than in kernel 4.4.0 so maybe its O_DIRECT paths weren't as performing in 4.4.0.

It could also be [MDEV-29967 broken linear read ahead](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29967) that we're working hard to fix before the next release.

It might also be the 10.6 statistics are different [try a recalculation using ANALYZE TABLES](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-30x-faster/).

There's a couple of btrfs links/suggestions in [this link](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23599).

Or it could be something totally different requiring:

- careful measurement and breakdown of individual queries and their execution.
- elimination of local environment (running a 10.3 version in the container of the same version/configuration as the local package).

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! "innodb_flush_method=fsync" did the job, now container version is even slightly faster than the native (packaged) one!

One question left: you mentioned this solution "as a workaround", and mentioned "innodb_buffer_pool_size" and "innodb_log_file_size".

Should I leave everything as they are now, or should I play around with "innodb_buffer_pool_size" and "innodb_log_file_size"? If so, then what are the suggested values for those? 
Thank you once again!

Comment: Yes, leave things as they are now. On `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, in `show global status like 'innodb_buffer_pool_read%'`, compare "reads" / "read_requests", the percentage should approach < %1 after reasonable amount of uptime. On `innodb_log_file_size`, depends on the write volume, there should be an existing answer somewhere. Ask a new question if its not clear.